# How do I update the state of a text widget?

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, state

I have been working with google sign in and I need to display the email but I can not get set state working can someone pls help!

Here is my current code:

```
const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9, 0, 9, 0),
        child: SignInButton(),
      ),
      Text(userEmail ?? 'email') // i need the email to update when i sign in 
    ],
  ),
 );
}
}

final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 dynamic? user;
 String? userEmail;
 String? userPhoneNumber;

 void getCurrentUserInfo() async {
   user = await _auth.currentUser!;
   userEmail = user.email;
   userPhoneNumber = user.phoneNumber;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void getCurrentUserInfo() async {
   user = await _auth.currentUser!;
   userEmail = user.email;
   userPhoneNumber = user.phoneNumber;
    setState((){})
}
```

assuming you are in a stateful widget. Just add `setState()` in `getCurrentUserInfo` and it should update the widget.

Comment: it shows set state is not defined as a function

Comment: you are probably not using a stateful widget then. Make sure that your widget is stateful.
update the question with full code and I will try to help. @meharker

Comment: ok so you where right it it was stateless thanks.

Comment: you're welcome. glad to help. @meharker